# Routes using annotations - passing custom variables and translation

Tags: laravel, annotations, laravel-routing, laravel-5, laravel-annotations

Using `routes.php` it's quite easy to create paths for different languages using prefixes, for example we can create for about page routes `about` and `pl/o-nas` urls to the same route using:

```
if (\Request::segment(1) =='pl') {
    $prefix ='pl';
    \App::setLocale('pl');
}
else{
    $prefix ='';
    \App::setLocale('en');
}

Route::group(
    array('prefix' => $prefix,
    function () {
        Route::any('/'.trans('routes.about'), 'Controller@action'); 
    }
);
```

But as we know Laravel 5 by default uses annotation. Is it possible to achieve the same using annotations? At the moment there are not many information about using annotations in Laravel 5.

You can first add to `RouteServiceProver` into `before` method the similar code:

```
if (\Request::segment(1) =='en') {
    $routePrefix ='';
    $this->app->setLocale('en');
}
else{
    $routePrefix ='pl';
    $this->app->setLocale('pl');
}
```

but how we can use this prefix and translation in annotations itself and how to use trans function here? It should be something like this but it obviously won't work because you cannot simply put function into annotation and I don't know if there is any way to add prefix here.

```
/**
 * @Get("/trans('routes.about')")
 * @prefix: {$prefix}
 */
public function about()
{
   return "about page";
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps use Middleware, parse the route for any language requirements - and set it in Middleware, before it gets to your controller?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Probably I could but at this moment I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

class LangDetection implements Middleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->segment(1) =='en') {
              $this->app->setLocale('en');
        }
        else{
              $this->app->setLocale('pl');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Then to make sure that is run on every call - put it into the application middleware stack (app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php):

```
protected $stack = [
    'App\Http\Middleware\LangDetection',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\Guard',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\Queue',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\Reader',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\Writer',
];
```

Edit: alternatively you dont have to put it in the stack, you can leave it as a 'middleware filter' and just call it on specific routes - same as you already do for 'auth', 'csrf' etc

Comment: The problem is that this Middleware should also modify request (remove prefix from url) and also translate routes to go to correct controller (now if I have url 'pl/o-nas` this Middleware will set language properly but it will still look  for `pl/o-nas` annotation and not `about`)

Comment: You could create a new $request object in your middleware, without the prefix - and then pass it to `$next($request)`. If the middleware runs in your main stack, it occurs *before* determining which route to run, so it will then pick the correct controller

Comment: Could you please show how can I change $request URL / create new request object easily based on current url? I haven't done it before and I don't know how could I do it. I don't know if I just should create new Request or clone current one and somehow edit url to make sure Request have also method (POST/GET/) and other necessary data.